# Accessing buttons from a movieclip to mainframe

Tags: actionscript-3

so I have a bunch of buttons inside a movieclip and I want to access the object of those and be able to modify them through the code of the mainframe, how can I do something like that?

I tried getChildByName() but nothing's happening.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e26.html

Comment: If you have everything placed on the main timeline you can access objects by instance name. Let's say your movieclip with buttons has the instance name "myMC" and a button inside of that movieclip has the instance name "myButton". Then in the main timeline you could access it like myMC.myButton.visible = false;